# Output videos are not overwritten. Automatically rename output video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mp4

I'm having problems with my videos coming out. Every time I create a new video they always overwrite the old one.
I want to find a way to automatically rename the output video every time I render so it won't be overwritten.
For example, they will number themselves instead of overwriting them. output1.mp4..output2.mp4...
Apply to the above line of code ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output\output.mp4
Please help me to get the best suggestion. Thank you

Comment: "above line of code ".. where is the full code? it's a batch file?

Comment: I simply want it to be able to automatically rename the output. The simple line of code above it is just an example

Comment: y not just "construct" the list in excel.. then paste it as one go instead..

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method I'm using is to add some (self)changing string at the end of the output filename. I often use additional 14 characters to add the date and time. The general example to use it in a batch file will look like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output\output_%date:~2,2%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.mp4
```

This example will create all output files as `output_YYMMDD_HHMMSS.mp4` for me - you can modify the numbers I used for my date/time format and adjust them to the one you are using.

Comment: thanks for the help. I will try it